# Dev и production контейнеры в Docker

Tags: docker

Веду разработку проекта и в будущем мне понадобится вести разработку не "по живому" в продакшене, а делать правки в Dev окружении и выкатывать в продакшен. Спросил у преподавателя, как это можно сделать, на что получил ответ - "используй Docker". Действительно ли можно реализовать механизм, описанный выше при помощи Docker? Я что-то не нашёл ни одной статьи на эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

Уверен, что можно....
Только надо научиться устанавливать docker, билдить имиджи, (пере)запускать контейнеры... Если для тестов надо еще и доступ давать вторым/третим лицам - надо еще и сервер для этого иметь :-) 
В общем это больше тема Devops - если есть у вас инфраструктурные инженеры - надо у них проконсультироваться...

Answer (score 0):

1) Изучить docker-compose. Особенно как он склеивает файлы и override файлы. https://habrahabr.ru/post/322440/

2) Создать файлы на разные окружения.

docker-compose.yml - base config (сюда пишем общее для всех)

docker-compose.development.yml - dev (специфика только для dev)

docker-compose.production.yml - prod

etc ...

3) `docker-compose up` по дефолту запустит только `docker-compose.yml`, поэтому делаем override.

```
ln -s docker-compose.development.yml docker-compose.override.yml
```

4) `docker-compose up` запускает dev версию. По аналогии можно запустить и  production, etc.

5) Также бывает специфичное взаимодействие сети например swarm.

Делаем ещё конфиг docker-compose.swarm.yml. Пишем туда специфику.

```
docker-compose config -f file -f file -f file
```

Смотрим, что получилось. Порядок очень важен.

5) Для деплоя изучить swarm, docker stack

6) Если в k8s полез там тоже есть как деплоить docker-compose файлы